# Mongo Query in nodejs for each element of array in each documents array properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi i am new to the mongodb please help

```
i get the string array as an input
arr = ['0-3333','0-22222','0-11122']
colection name is device
mongo document structure is like that: 
{
name:'abcd',
properties:
 {  
   device:['0-333','0-222','0-112'],
   status: 'OK'
 },
region:'USA'
}
```

I want all the documents that have at least one of the elements of arr as mentioned above and status is OK for the document.
what will be the mongodb query for nodejs.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Does find with $in not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
db.device.find({
  properties:
     {
       device: { $in: arr }
     }
  });
```